# YouTube Regex replacement C# breaking HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using this code toe place YouTube URLs with an icon that when you click on it, it opens a lightbox that shows the video.

Here's the C# code:

```
 const string pattern = @"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:(?:(?:youtube.com\/watch\?[^?]*v=|youtu.be\/)([\w\-]+))(?:[^\s?]+)?)";
        const string replacement = "<a title='Click to watch the video' rel='nofollow' class='youtube-popup' href='//www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1' data-lity><span class='fa fa-play'></span>Watch</a>";

 var rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 var result = rgx.Replace(theinput, replacement);
  if(result != null && result != "")
  {
            return result;
  }
```

The code replaces the video URLs and shows the icons, but also cuts the HTML after it (`<p class="tags"></p>`) and it gets cut to  `class='tags'>` (both the paragraph tags are not present, and because of that, it places in an element before it that contains the links.

I tested it with two links in the same paragraph, separated with text and spaces between them of course.

How can I changed the Regex to work and not break the HTML for this particular example?

Comment: Doing this with regex is highly misguided. Why not use an HTML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex seems to work for me. I'm not completely sure on all the formats that YouTube URLS can come in. Your Regex was not stopping at the `<` and was continuing on until the first space (before `class`), hence why it was eating some of the following tags. Also note that you need to escape the `.` inside of `youtube.com` and `youtu.be`

`(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:(?:(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?[^?]*v=|youtu\.be\/)))([\w-]+)`

Also please keep in mind: [You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/491907)

Comment: It didn't east my links, but part of the paragraph after it, the <p part. I use a regular URL link copied from the address bar. I am giving it a try

Comment: Works. Thanks my friend.